Mockito not working for inner method variable of HttpURLConnection
this is the method  for which junit is written
public boolean isSelfServicePortalServerAvailable(String crmEndPoint) {
        boolean isServerAvailable = false;
        URL url = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(crmEndPoint);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            isServerAvailable = true;
            connection.disconnect();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return isServerAvailable;
    }

This is the test case wriiten
@Mock
private URL mockUrl;

@Mock
private HttpURLConnection mockConnection;

@Mock
private ISelfServiceDao selfServiceDao;

@Mock
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@InjectMocks
private SelfServiceCoreClaimImpl selfServiceCoreClaimImpl = new SelfServiceCoreClaimImpl(restTemplate);



@Test
public void testIsSelfServicePortalServerAvailable_Success() throws IOException {
    
    when(mockUrl.openConnection()).thenReturn(mockConnection);
    doNothing().when(mockConnection).connect();
    doNothing().when(mockConnection).disconnect();

    boolean result = selfServiceCoreClaimImpl.isSelfServicePortalServerAvailable("http://test-url.com");
    assertTrue(result);
}


errors org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnnecessaryStubbingException:
Unnecessary stubbings detected.
Clean & maintainable test code requires zero unnecessary code.
Following stubbings are unnecessary (click to navigate to relevant line of code):


-> at com.acentra.ssp.impl.SelfServiceCoreClaimImplTest.testIsSelfServicePortalServerAvailable_Success(SelfServiceCoreClaimImplTest.java:71)
-> at com.acentra.ssp.impl.SelfServiceCoreClaimImplTest.testIsSelfServicePortalServerAvailable_Success(SelfServiceCoreClaimImplTest.java:72)
-> at com.impl.SelfServiceCoreClaimImplTest.testIsSelfServicePortalServerAvailable_Success(SelfServiceCoreClaimImplTest.java:73)
Please remove unnecessary stubbings More info: javadoc for UnnecessaryStubbingException class.
at org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension.afterEach(MockitoExtension.java:192)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)

Not calling mock ... can someone help me on this

I would try:
    public boolean isSelfServicePortalServerAvailable(String crmEndPoint) {
        boolean isServerAvailable = false;
        try {
            HttpURLConnection connection = getHttpURLConnection(crmEndPoint);
            connection.connect();
            isServerAvailable = true;
            connection.disconnect();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return isServerAvailable;
    }

    private HttpURLConnection getHttpURLConnection(String crmEndPoint) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(crmEndPoint);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        return connection;
    }

And then test
    @Mock
    private HttpURLConnection mockConnection;

    @Mock
    private ISelfServiceDao selfServiceDao;

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    @Spy
    private SelfServiceCoreClaimImpl selfServiceCoreClaimImpl;



    @Test
    public void testIsSelfServicePortalServerAvailable_Success() throws IOException {
        String crmEndPoint = "http://test-url.com";
        doReturn(mockConnection).when(selfServiceCoreClaimImpl).getHttpURLConnection(crmEndPoint);
        doNothing().when(mockConnection).connect();
        doNothing().when(mockConnection).disconnect();

        boolean result = selfServiceCoreClaimImpl.isSelfServicePortalServerAvailable(crmEndPoint);
        assertTrue(result);
    }


You can't just inject mock for objects that are created inside the method (like the new URL(crmEndPoint);).
The @InjectMocks will automatically inject the mocks inside private fields, or setters or constructor parameters.
If an object is created inside a method then you have to consider the following:

Is this object a stateless? Then I have to receive it from the constructor or DI system and then mock it. So I have to refactor the method and remove the creation of the new object.
Is this object a DTO? Then I don't need to mock it.
If none of the above, which means the object creation can't be avoided, (probably your case as I can tell) then you have to use the MockedConstruction.
Also for the mocked construction to work you will need the following dependency in Maven:

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
    <version>some version here</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


I've done few tweaking in your junit, and it runs perfectly fine.
    @Test
    public void testIsSelfServicePortalServerAvailable_Success() throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection mockConnection = Mockito.mock(HttpURLConnection.class);
        URL mockUrl = Mockito.mock(URL.class);
        SelfServiceCoreClaimImpl selfServiceCoreClaimImpl= new SelfServiceCoreClaimImpl();
        Mockito.doReturn(mockConnection).when(mockUrl).openConnection();
        Mockito.doNothing().when(mockConnection).connect();
        Mockito.doNothing().when(mockConnection).disconnect();

        boolean result = selfServiceCoreClaimImpl.isSelfServicePortalServerAvailable("http://test-url.com");
        assertTrue(result);
    }


@Sneaky Throw do i need to use this ?

It is a lombok annotation basically needed to suppress exceptions. No it is not really needed

@dhS removed annotation you can use vanilla java also

Not working for me Zahid

@dhS whats the issue?

Somehow mocks are not working as expected and real code is hitting.

Is the code available on github? If so, can you provide me the link?
